# How to remove startup terminal "GNU GRUB version 2.02" on Linux Mint 20 cinamon?

Tags: linux-mint, grub, startup

I installed Linux Mint 20 on a clean drive, but I keep getting this terminal on startup.

```
                             GNU GRUB  version 2.02

   Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
   lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
   device or file completions.


grub> _
```

I'm new to Linux and have no idea what it is for, but I never saw it on Mint 19 before. I can skip it with "exit" command, but I'd like to avoid it completely. I found many discussions on this topic, but they were all talking about dual booting issues, which doesn't apply in my case.

I tried editing this grub config file via:

```
xed admin:///etc/default/grub
```

And this is it's current state:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

One comment mentioned "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" so here it is:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon' --class linuxmint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec ro  quiet splash 
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec' {
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic' --class linuxmint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-42-generic-advanced-9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-42-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec ro  quiet splash 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic (recovery mode)' --class linuxmint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-42-generic-recovery-9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-42-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.4.0-26-generic' --class linuxmint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-26-generic-advanced-9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec ro  quiet splash 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, with Linux 5.4.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class linuxmint --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-26-generic-recovery-9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=9352d93a-2417-49fe-8ed3-02e348bc18ec ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

"lsblk" command:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 232,4G  0 part /
```

======================================

UEFI menu had 4 options: Ubuntu, Ubuntu, SSD and some kind of setup. First Ubuntu option starts up my OS in a regular way, first showing this GRUB menu, then I enter "exit", and then Mint loads. Second Ubuntu, gives me 2 GRUB menus, one after another, and then Mint loads. Choosing SSD will bypass these GRUB menus (won't show them at all), which is my desired outcome.

SOLUTION: in BIOS, I just moved SSD to be a first boot option and GRUB console is no more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you recently installed a new version of the OS, the 'console' you see might be an obsolete installation of GRUB which is not maintained by your currently booted system. You would need to adjust the system's boot order settings to avoid the obsolete instance of GRUB, and possibly then delete it from the system.

Try running `sudo efibootmgr -v` and copy & edit the output into your original question.

If your system boots in UEFI-style, you might have a minor Secure Boot-related issue: the installation scripts may have initially created a "plain" boot entry for GRUB without the Secure Boot shim bootloader, and another boot option with the Secure Boot `shimx64.efi` bootloader. If Secure Boot is in effect, the "plain" GRUB won't be able to load any executable code because GRUB modules won't use the Windows PE executable format recognized by Secure Boot. As a result, it drops into GRUB shell prompt.

Once you exit the "plain" GRUB, another boot entry starts GRUB through the `shimx64.efi` bootloader, which allows GRUB to work in presence of Secure Boot.

If this is the problem you're having, you'll just need to identify the boot entry that uses the `shimx64.efi` and make it the first in the firmware boot order. The `efibootmgr` command can do that.

It might even be that an old boot entry from the previous Mint 19 installation is still present and causing the confusion.

In the `sudo efibootmgr -v` output, the first line should be `BootCurrent: XXXX` where `XXXX` will be a four-digit hexadecimal number. It identifies the boot entry that booted the currently running OS. If its number is not currently the first on the `BootOrder:` line of the output, you will need to fix it.

So, if the `sudo efibootmgr -v` output will look something like this:

```
BootCurrent: XXXX
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: YYYY, XXXX, ZZZZ, <...possibly other numbers...>
BootXXXX* Mint 20 <....> File(\EFI\Mint\SHIMX64.EFI)
<other boot entries...>
```

Here `BootXXXX` is not currently the first one in `BootOrder`, so you will need to make it the first one, like this:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ,<any other Boot numbers listed in the original BootOrder line...>
```

Note that while the original `BootOrder:` line has spaces after the commas, you should not use spaces when specifying the boot numbers for the `sudo efibootmgr -o ...` command.

Comment: This answer is good. However, it would benefit from a "TL;DR variant" at the top: "The 'console' you see likely is an obsolete installation of GRUB which is *not* maintained by your currently booted system. Delete or disable the old installation."

Comment: @Hermann Indeed, edited.

Comment: after running "sudo efibootmgr -v" I just get "EFI variables are not supported on this system"

Comment: @Frogmaz Then you are not booting in UEFI mode. If you have multiple disks and you didn't wipe them all when installing Mint 20, it's possible that one of your disks still has a GRUB from Mint 19 in its MBR, and that disk happens to be the first one in the BIOS boot order. Or if your system supports UEFI but is configured to make both UEFI and legacy-style boot attempts, that might complicate things more still. The output of the `lsblk` command and a description/screenshot of your BIOS boot settings could help us better understand your situation.

Comment: @telcoM Thank your for having patience with me, I have very little idea of what I'm doing when I read your instructions. When I turn on my computer, I press F12 in order to get to this UEFI menu (correct?). I then have 4 options: Ubuntu, Ubuntu, SSD and some kind of setup. First Ubuntu option starts up my OS in a regular way, first showing this GRUB menu, then I enter "exit", and then Mint loads. Second Ubuntu, gives me 2 GRUB menus, one after another, and then Mint loads. Choosing SSD will bypass these GRUB menus (won't show them at all), which is my desired outcome.

Comment: Choosing setup option does nothing, just black screen, so I restart after 2 minutes. I'm guessing there is a way to make SSD option a default one?

I'm really a newbie, not just with Linux, but with this kind of tinkering as well, so I appreciate your effort a lot.

Comment: So I updated my post with 'lsblk' output. In bios, I have 3 boot options. ubuntu, ubuntu i SSD. I choose SSD to be first now, maybe that will resolve the issue?

Comment: @telcoM Yup, putting SSD as a first boot option did what I was hoping it will. No more GRUB menu. :D Thanks a lot. Do you know why do I have these 2 extra ubuntu boot options? And would you happen to know how would one start learning about all of this? Maybe a book or online course?

Comment: Your system is actually UEFI-capable, and the previous Ubuntus were installed in native UEFI style, but your current Mint 20 installation is apparently done in legacy BIOS style. [Roderick W. Smith has written a great set of web pages about rEFInd bootloader](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), but they also cover a lot of general UEFI basics and complications caused by firmware bugs and less-than-perfect legacy compatibility mechanisms. When UEFI was introduced, it changed the boot procedure which had been essentially the same since the late 1980s... no wonder it caused some confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, been a while since I've looked at GRUB in particular.. That being said, you can do exactly the same as I would have to. Read through plaintext files in /boot and the GRUB documentation online. It's especially important if your new to linux to do.

Your /etc/default/grub looks the same as mine.
All I can think of is there's another instance uncommented of #GRUB_TERMINAL="console" in /boot/grub/grub.cfg or your missing menu entries in that file.

Entries and menu labels can all be in /boot/grub/grub.cfg or that file will point to multiple other plaintext files with the information.

You should see menu entries in a similar format:

```
menuentry "Start Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit" {
set gfxpayload=keep
linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --
initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
```

Other relevant files to GRUB and booting are usually located within the same directory as the splash image file or nearby.

You can try:
`sudo find /boot -type f -iname *.png`

Comment: "sudo find /boot -type f -iname *.png" gives no output for me, but I updated my post to include "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" in case it might help